# Jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, linux, terminal, jarsigner

I try to sign an original APK which I have embedded with a Metasploit payload.
Like this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA [apk_path] androiddebugkey
```

But it gives this error:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /root/.android/debug.keystore (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running msfupdate in terminal. I had the same problem.
By running msfupdate you download a 70mb archieve in your linux and it gets installed automatically.